# Как правильно найти число, являющееся некоторой степенью двойки?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Условие: Программа должна ввести из консоли натуральное число `number` и найти следующее
число за `number`, что является некоторой степенью двойки.

```
Входные данные:
Естественное число n.

Исходные данные:
Ответ на задачу.
```

Пример:

```
Входные данные #1
7

Выходные данные #1
8
```

Мой код максимально простой, но проходит на `90%` из-за нехватки времени:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int number = 0;
    int result = 1;
    std::cin >> number;

    while(number >= result) {
        result = result * 2;
    }

    std::cout << result << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Очевидно потому, что тут делается безосновательное предположение о том, что число поместится в int.

Comment: [std::bit_ceil](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_ceil)

Comment: Вам нужно эффективно найти число лидирующих нулевых бит. Для этого используют функцию, которую обычно называют CLZ (или NLZ). В GNU можно использовать [__builtin_clz](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/72437). А вот ряд реализаций [NLZ](https://github.com/hcs0/Hackers-Delight/blob/master/nlz.c.txt) на С++

Answer (score 2):

Можно манипулировать битами. Установим все младшие биты (1) до самого старшего установленного, и следующим числом будет степень двойки:

```
--number;
//сдвинуть вправо на 1, 2, 4,..., половина количества бит
//для 32 бит будет 2^4
for(unsigned k = 0; k <= 4; ++k)
    number |= number >> (1 << k);
cout <<++number;
```

Для маленьких чисел ваш вариант может решить меньше чем за 4 цикла, но для чисел >16 этот вариант оптимальнее

p.s.
теперь поговорим о недоработках в вашем коде. Не сложно заметить, что для отрицательных чисел при вводе `std::cin >> number;` ваш цикл просто ничего не будет делать, так как условие `number >= result` не выполнится изначально. И, в итоге, для любого отрицательного числа, получите не верный ответ _ первоначальное значение

```
int result = 1
```

При желании, сами догадаетесь как изменить условие для отрицательных чисел. **Но**,
так как степень двойки не может быть отрицательным числом, то вариант для отрицательных чисел отпадает, и тип должен быть без знаковым.
Для типов **без** знаковых(например unsigned int number), number в любом случаи >=0(отрицательное число автоматом приравнивается с большим положительным), и решение будет верным.

Comment: Красивое решение!

Comment: Для современных процессоров имеет смысл вручную развернуть цикл в 5 строк (а способ интересный (из Hackers-Delight?)) / Кстати, не все же внимательно читают условия в вопросе. Укажите в ответе, что способ работает только для положительных (number > 0) значений

Comment: @avp,  может вы правы , а способ мне знаком давно _ не помню уже откуда, но был повод и желание решать подобные задачи.

Comment: Тогда вам может понравиться https://github.com/hcs0/Hackers-Delight

Comment: Способ пожалуй и красив, но совсем не ясен.

Comment: @Denys,  Ну это объяснить не долго я не могу.  Это обыкновенный мат. анализ. Если поэкспериментируете на примерах, внимательно следя как меняются биты, думаю сами поймете.  А красота не причем _ главное решить так, чтобы  это решение удовлетворяло требованиям

Comment: Вот например: что это за действие `|=` ?

Comment: Это битовое  "или". Если не знаете битовые операции, то и говорить не о чем. Если занимаетесь программированием, их нужно обязательно знать

Comment: Хорошо поизучаю ето. Но стоило мне заменить `int number = 0` на `unsigned number = 0` и тоже самое сделать с `result` - задача проходит на все `100%`. В чем суть?

Comment: @Denys, Ну вот, добавил в ответ подробные разъяснения